# passing command line arguments having dot operator in it

Tags: linux, perl

i was trying to parse one of the website while doing so i need to pass

```
$url="http://www.hotels.com/search/search.html?destinationName=Dallas%2C+Texas%2C+United+States&arrivalDate=10%2F27%2F11&departureDate=10%2F31%2F11&numberOfRooms=1&numberOfAdults=1";
system("perl x.pl $url"); // this is giving me error because the $url consists of dot operator.
```

Comment: Why are you using `system` from Perl to run another Perl script?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Why not?  It's like invoking any other command from a Perl script.  (You probably could incorporate `x.pl` into the calling script, but that's not necessarily the best solution.)

Comment: @BenVoigt, Because the code is available as a script and not as a module?

Answer (score 7):

The multi-argument from of `system()` is better in this case:

```
system('perl', 'x.pl', $url);
```

When you pass `system()` a single string that contains any shell metacharacters (including spaces), it invokes it via `/bin/sh` (at least on Unix-like systems) -- which means that things like the `&` character are going to be interpreted by the shell unless (as @MikePlayle suggests) you quote it.

But when you give `system()` multiple arguments, it bypasses the shell and executes the command named in the first argument directly, passing it the other arguments.

The single-argument form is useful when you want the shell to handle metacharacters -- for example, if you want to do I/O redirection (including pipes) and/or wildcard expansion, things that *can* be done in Perl, but with a bit more effort.

`perldoc perlfunc` and search for "system" for more information, or [see here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Comment: If only `system` always behaved as the multi-arg form and another builtin (`shell`) executed a shell command...  Anyway, [IPC::System](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::System)'s functions automatically handle error checking, so I'd go with its `systemx` instead.

Comment: @ikegami: Backward compatibility is a harsh mistress.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to put quotes round the URL so the shell doesn't try to interpret it.

Try something like

```
system("perl x.pl \"$url\"");
```

Or whatever the Perl syntax is for quotes. I'm sure someone will correct me if I've got it wrong.

Comment: Mike - while you guessed correctly, it's kind of rude to post an answer you don't know the rightness of. If you don't know enough about escaping quotes in Perl, either don't post, or better yet spend 1-5 minutes Googling and post after you did the research.

Comment: Mike, you're correct.  You could also use single quotes: `system("perl x.pl '$url'");`.  Or see my answer for (IMHO) a better solution.

Comment: @DVK: You have a point, but it's better than posting answers without acknowledging uncertainty.  Mike correctly diagnosed the problem based on his knowledge of shell syntax, and admitted that he was guessing (correctly, as it turns out) about the specific Perl syntax.  Even if he'd guessed wrong, he provided enough information for the OP to figure out the solution.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, depends on the shell. Some shells would require double quotes.

Comment: @ikegami: The only such shell I can think of is the Windows cmd.exe (and the question is tagged [tag:linux].  What shell do you have in mind?

Comment: @Keith Thompson, That's the one, missed the tag. Maybe Mike Playle did too.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I agree - your answer is technically better for at least two reasons: it avoids the overhead of running the shell, and it avoids possible security problems due to the shell interpreting potentially untrusted data. (+1) DVK: Sorry, I'll try to be more sure of myself in future!